# shared instance with 2 API's error: Can't add self as subview

Tags: ios7, self, xcode-storyboard, performselector

Am using 2 different API's having trouble with view controller logic. First API is Quickblox as they require loading first which I do in AppDelegate.m in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. This works correctly. When I try to transition to the second API is where I run into trouble.

First Error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'sightingsTableViewController''

To correct I added 'sightingsTableViewController' in the Storyboard. Went to SightingsTableView Controller then added 'sightingsTableViewController' to the Storyboard ID Identity. This fixed the error...

The app went a little further then got second log error:

...nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar

...Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for 
  .
  Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
True to the error as I tried to back out to previous screens I get stack dump with error:

Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview' Storyboard The view controller logic is wrong and would like to better understand how to correct.

I can get the SightingsTableViewController to display after I changed a delay to 3 seconds.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showProximityServicesSwitchViewAndNavigationBar) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

[self performSelector:@selector(initializeFyxService) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];

[image: Storyboard Layout]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking the button 'Sign In' to create the push to the Sightings Table View Controller, I clicked the SignInViewController and dragged the push to the Sightings TVC.

I do not know why this fixed the problem but I do not get any errors or stack dumps now. I would love to know why this change would resolve the unbalanced errors.